# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘plyr’

Tags: r, rstudio, plyr, rcpp

Firstly, I am very new to this and am required to use `R` and `RStudio` for a class of mine.  My professor hasn't been able to figure out how to help me, and I am very stuck.  I have an assignment due Wednesday and I'm in deep trouble.

I am getting the error "**`Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘plyr`’**", every time I try to use the command `library(plyr)` in `RStudio`, and I have already downloaded `plyr`.  However, there appears to be an issue when downloading it.

Whenever I download it it says:

```
package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\Mathew\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\file8b0732c54a\Rcpp’ to ‘C:\Users\Mathew\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\Rcpp’
package ‘plyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

Therefore I think the problem is with `Rcpp`. But when I try to download it, I get this message:

```
package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\Mathew\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\file8b067215908\Rcpp’ to ‘C:\Users\Mathew\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\Rcpp’
The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Mathew\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0I6V54\downloaded_packages
```

`library(plyr)` still will not run.  I have downloaded them both and deleted them, tried installing the latest `Java`, restarting my pc, and nothing works.  Can anyone please help me?  I am desperate.

Bless You All,
Mathew

Comment: Try to start R with administrator privileges before installing the package.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8.1, sorry should have stated that.  So I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but running with administrator privileges did not seem to help as it still will not run.

Comment: To investigate possible points of friction between Rstudio and WIndows, you could try Process Monitor: https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx ...hit CTRL+A for autoscroll and see if there are any failed operations.

Comment: Also, this seems to be highly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308639/r-cran-install-library-rcpp-fails-after-r3-2-upgrade

Comment: Yes, it is a dupe. You *simply cannot update a package you already have loaded* -- it is a Windows system constraint.