# Creating lagged (t-1) independent variables in Panel data

Tags: r, lag, finance, panel-data, performanceanalytics

Say that I want to regress the predictive model: Return_t = x + Volume_t-1 + Volatility_t-1 + e. I have a 5-year weekly panel data with 28 companies already prepared in excel and looks like this:

```
ID  Date        Return      Volume       Volatility
1   2012-01-10  0.039441572 0.6979594    0.2606079
1   2012-01-17 -0.021107681 0.6447289    0.3741519
1   2012-01-24  0.004798082 1.0072677    0.3097104
1   2012-01-31  0.001559987 1.0066153    0.2761096
1   2012-02-07 -0.009058289 0.7218983    0.2592109
1   2012-02-14  0.046404936 1.2879986    0.4304542
2   2012-01-10  0.02073912 -0.141970906  0.2573633
2   2012-01-17 -0.00369127  0.007792180  0.3360240
2   2012-01-24 -0.05881038  0.001347634  0.2163933
2   2012-01-31 -0.05664598  0.640085029  0.3545598
2   2012-02-07  0.03654193  0.360513703  0.3594383
2   2012-02-14  0.03092432  0.105669775  0.3043643
```

I want to lag the independent variables setting it to t-1, which package allows me to do that in R? I am going to run a panel data regression with fixed effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After grouping by 'ID', we can use `lag` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Volume_1 = lag(Volume), Volatility_1 = lag(Volatility))
```

---

Or another option is `shift` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- c("Volume", "Volatility")
setDT(df1)[, paste0(nm1, "_1") := lapply(.SD, shift), by = ID, .SDcols = nm1]
```

Comment: I have problems with using dplyr. When I try to open it I get the error message: Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘rlang’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’

Comment: @NeriKim The new version of R is 3.4.0.  Can you update to new version and then install dplyr

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will look into it

Comment: I updated R to the new version, now I get the error message: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘Rcpp’

Comment: @NeriKim  Have you tried installing `Rcpp` i.e. `install.packages("Rcpp")`

Comment: I'm using R studio and I have both versions of R; the old and the updated version. I guess I have to uninstall the old R version, so the packages are moved into the right folder because it says it wasnt able to move the package to the R 3.4 folder..

Comment: @NeriKim  Are you using windows?

Comment: yes, I am using windows.

Comment: @NeriKim  That is strange, I am also using windows.  I think when you install packages in the new R version, it should ask for creating a new folder, right

Comment: Maybe I should just uninstall everything and Install it over again..

Comment: @NeriKim Let me try to understand, when you are installing packages, is it going to install on system level or does it create a new folder `R` in "Documents"

Comment: when I tried to install Rcpp, the following message I get is this:

Comment: Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/neri_/OneDrive/Dokumenter/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/Rcpp_0.12.11.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3380287 bytes (3.2 MB)
downloaded 3.2 MB

Comment: package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\neri_\OneDrive\Dokumenter\R\win-library\3.4\file4efc2836329c\Rcpp’ to ‘C:\Users\neri_\OneDrive\Dokumenter\R\win-library\3.4\Rcpp’

The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\neri_\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaOZSUs\downloaded_packages

Comment: @NeriKim Is there any permission issues

Comment: I tried to uninstall and install the programs again. Now I can't even open other packages which I could before because of the 'Rcpp' error message.

Comment: @NeriKim  Can you try uninstalling the whole R and do the installation again.  Try opening on R console and check

Comment: I see this is a common problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308639/r-cran-install-library-rcpp-fails-after-r3-2-upgrade

Comment: It was because of the McAfee Antivirus, I deactivated and now it works fine! So sorry about this.

Comment: So say that my df is called Paneldata, Paneldata %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
mutate(Volume_1 = lag(Volume), Volatility_1 = lag(Volatility))  Then I got this error message: Error in resolve_vars(new_groups, tbl_vars(.data)) : 
  unknown variable to group by : ID.

Comment: @NeriKim  I am not sure about the error message.  Have you loaded plyr package also.  Try it on a fresh session with only `dplyr` loaded

Comment: It seems to be working now. How do I create a new output with the lagged variables?

Comment: @NeriKim  Are you saying that this   `PaneldataN <- Paneldata %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Volume_1 = lag(Volume), Volatility_1 = lag(Volatility))` not working

Comment: It is working now! I messed up a bit. Strange, the "lagged variables" are not lagged though..

Comment: @NeriKim  What do you mean by not lagged though?  Isn't `lag` not working?

Comment: No, Volume_1 and Volatility_1 are not lagged with t-1. Could it be that the df is in the wrong format? This df is imported directly from excel..

Comment: @NeriKim  It could be.  What is the `str(Paneldata)` ?

Comment: Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 7280 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Company ID: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Obs       : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Date      : POSIXct, format: "2012-01-10" "2012-01-17" ...
 $ Return    : num  0.03944 -0.02111 0.0048 0.00156 -0.00906 ...
 $ Volume    : num  0.698 0.645 1.007 1.007 0.722 ...
 $ Volatility: num  0.261 0.374 0.31 0.276 0.259 ...

Comment: @NeriKim  It looks alright.  Can you try `dplyr::lag(Volume), Volatility_1 = dplyr::lag(Volatility)` in the `mutate` in case `lag` got masked

Comment: Thank you so much! Now everything is working!

Comment: @NeriKim  Great, there is `lag` from `base R`, that could have masked it

Comment: Sorry, there is one final thing remaining. The lag should be within group, in this case within the Company ID. I apologize for not making this clear. Is that still possible in dplyr?

Comment: To be more precise, the first observation within the groups (Company ID) should be NA, like it is in the first group

Comment: @NeriKim  yes, it is within group, we used `group_by(ID)` i.e. `df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(Volume_1 = dplyr::lag(Volume), Volatility_1 = dplyr::lag(Volatility))
# A tibble: 12 x 7
# Groups:   ID [2]
      ID       Date       Return       Volume Volatility     Volume_1 Volatility_1
   <int>      <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
 1     1 2012-01-10  0.039441572  0.697959400  0.2606079           NA           NA`

Comment: Hmm, but in the output it takes the last observation from the previous group instead of NA

Comment: @NeriKim  What is the version of your `dplyr`?  I am getting NA

Comment: It is 0.5, should I update it to 0.7?

Comment: @NeriKim  yes, mine is 0.7

Comment: Hmm, I trying to update it, but it wont.. :/

Comment: nevermind, newbie as I am, I opened dplyr befor plyr. I closed R and opened it again and opened the packages in the correct order. That was the problem, now it is fine. Sorry about this. Still new in R

Comment: @NeriKim Yes, plyr::summarise or `plyr::mutate` might have messed it.  If there are same functions from different packages, use `dplyr::mutate(Volume_1 = ...`

Comment: Anyway, I cannot thank enough for your help. You have saved my thesis!

Comment: @NeriKim  Glad to be part of your success

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `mutate_at` and then join back:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_at(4:5, lag) %>% 
  left_join(df, ., by = c('ID','Date','Return'))
```

The output:

```
   ID       Date       Return     Volume.x Volatility.x     Volume.y Volatility.y
1   1 2012-01-10  0.039441572  0.697959400    0.2606079           NA           NA
2   1 2012-01-17 -0.021107681  0.644728900    0.3741519  0.697959400    0.2606079
3   1 2012-01-24  0.004798082  1.007267700    0.3097104  0.644728900    0.3741519
4   1 2012-01-31  0.001559987  1.006615300    0.2761096  1.007267700    0.3097104
5   1 2012-02-07 -0.009058289  0.721898300    0.2592109  1.006615300    0.2761096
6   1 2012-02-14  0.046404936  1.287998600    0.4304542  0.721898300    0.2592109
7   2 2012-01-10  0.020739120 -0.141970906    0.2573633  1.287998600    0.4304542
8   2 2012-01-17 -0.003691270  0.007792180    0.3360240 -0.141970906    0.2573633
9   2 2012-01-24 -0.058810380  0.001347634    0.2163933  0.007792180    0.3360240
10  2 2012-01-31 -0.056645980  0.640085029    0.3545598  0.001347634    0.2163933
11  2 2012-02-07  0.036541930  0.360513703    0.3594383  0.640085029    0.3545598
12  2 2012-02-14  0.030924320  0.105669775    0.3043643  0.360513703    0.3594383
```